# Why are emails sent from my domain to my gmail account, blocked by iCloud?

Tags: mail.app, gmail

This happens periodically and I have never been able to figure it out even after many years.  Finally deciding to ask the web.

I have a domain with Wordpress on it, on my own hosting account at Hostgator.  On that domain I have plugins such as WordFence which occasionally send me emails about things.  These emails are sent to my gmail.com address.  The email address on the Hostgator account is also the gmail address.  My iCloud address (@me.com) is not associated with the domain, hosting account, or plugins in any way.

On occasion I get rejection emails from iCloud, as if I have been sending spam or something from my iCloud address.  Here is an example that just came (personal info redacted):

> The response from the remote server was: 550 5.7.1 [CS01] Message
>   rejected due to local policy. Please visit
>   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; googlemail.com Received-From-MTA: dns;
>   my_username@gator3035.hostgator.com Arrival-Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019
>   14:34:31 -0800 (PST) X-Original-Message-ID:
>   <773b12e625f3a1a11b8f5a98d6dfa2bc@my_domain.com>
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; my_address@me.com Action: failed Status:
>   5.7.1 Remote-MTA: dns; mx4.mail.icloud.com. (17.172.34.67, the server for the domain me.com.) Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.7.1 [CS01]
>   Message rejected due to local policy. Please visit
>   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137 Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 09
>   Dec 2019 14:34:33 -0800 (PST)
>
> From: WordPress   Subject: Wordfence activity
>   for December 9, 2019 on my_domain.com  Date: December 9, 2019 at
>   2:34:28 PM PST To: my_address@gmail.com

Why is iCloud even involved here, in any way?  The email in question was sent by Wordfence, to my gmail address.  The only time iCloud comes into play at all is when I retrieve emails since I'm using Mail.app.  But why would that have anything to do with this?  I don't get it.  Any input is appreciated.

EDIT:  Adding the complete headers here:

> Mail Delivery Subsystem   Delivery
>   Status Notification (Failure) To: my_address+caf_=my_address.com@gmail.com
>   Auto-Submitted: ⁨auto-replied⁩ Arc-Seal: ⁨i=1; a=rsa-sha256;
>   t=1575930873; cv=none; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
>   b=Mmp9Br3lNM3rDahSJ/zFi4WVcvzlovXH3SHbSoJ4tofdOIV9nR+efYJ/RTSeTHoVib
>   C+VLYICot2FhZJa7NISPtUlrfRO6M7PnSLLqee+bpz/DpPc0bRhExE9qKmr9JTBjzcjx
>   1P/+tYZY1K2XAK7KVmxsF3a+lnsiajzW/XsiqGBefABfCzT+WbpHNNopKHAfnrHqJT2r
>   VQAnsBPobfO2+r5w21b9xNa2+uaWnGwDjONGr37P+VmBT2NS2krPDQFJVgsMsjurhJdA
>   D9xwf/Oqi0pilAXYvMTywoG8h1g5RC9UluTa61nlymRZQ5kHP5/1YD5F1BFDCX9UteVr
>   bV2w==⁩ ⁨<773b12e625f3a1a11b8f5a98d6dfa2bc@my_domain.com>⁩ X-Received:
>   ⁨by 2002:a0c:9304:: with SMTP id d4mr25612477qvd.12.1575930873794;
>   Mon, 09 Dec 2019 14:34:33 -0800 (PST)⁩ X-Received: ⁨by
>   2002:a05:6214:50f:: with SMTP id v15mr16843999qvw.42.1575930873697;
>   Mon, 09 Dec 2019 14:34:33 -0800 (PST)⁩ X-Gm-Message-State:
>   ⁨APjAAAU8bHrG50c6T4Mm5hJBfhUQwEiSCsl9zod3OkhNB8ls+8czmBj1
>   DJiXv/FVRpgDeELkiWIj+j8/lOOXLkKlJjWGYBNCtA==⁩ Return-Path: ⁨<>⁩
>   Return-Path: ⁨<>⁩ Arc-Authentication-Results: ⁨i=1; mx.google.com;
>   dkim=pass header.i=@googlemail.com header.s=20161025
>   header.b=BZLI4Xp0; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain
>   of postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as
>   permitted sender) smtp.helo=mail-sor-f69.google.com; dmarc=pass
>   (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=googlemail.com⁩
>   X-Google-Smtp-Source:
>   ⁨APXvYqzuASmjpUzQH5oRbGlMi6/AslW4bxLHFBzgmoCneaDkZnf3DXmt0gH4zcxLCrd16wwBz2K2QgrTDI6dC8v74rdt04GHQls3+rE=⁩
>   Authentication-Results: ⁨mx.google.com; dkim=pass
>   header.i=@googlemail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=BZLI4Xp0; spf=pass
>   (google.com: best guess record for domain of
>   postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as
>   permitted sender) smtp.helo=mail-sor-f69.google.com; dmarc=pass
>   (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=googlemail.com⁩
>   X-Failed-Recipients: ⁨my_address@me.com⁩ Arc-Message-Signature: ⁨i=1;
>   a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
>   h=in-reply-to:references:subject:from:date:message-id:auto-submitted
>   :to:dkim-signature; bh=+vVumkeSjV1UdpDo3N/fd36LuEEOvN9i2NfWLJL56oI=;
>   b=zBAX3npJdEzzzOqVQsmTCE4eG4Uy9HIA/FsPVPRRI2J4Ky+tEwuOAf+p82qsJTA4DE
>   G/5+uRPwRsJsGG8PntsLbLHfw+1W32jkRS5aBrnxiLS3lt475rO0vL88KB7C2Jke2Hpk
>   Lf8RRR8aT4AMfniCjpcaWxdvl20gTjZLxZwlkUthGZQ+yfUM2o1PtH2Snkds4fJ9uD2a
>   0uRXr4eN1P4893ngD9T50u87FperOjaLjmzTx2u33WwRMHkhVAHvxnbY1i0voFbCQ3e5
>   IG55BP8rwZgHZID2tORiQwUVVKXzOyZqtrgNuXh4niHZwz61uWVFrrRXqqqjzQR90gr2
>   QOnQ==⁩ Dkim-Signature: ⁨v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=googlemail.com; s=20161025;
>   h=to:auto-submitted:message-id:date:from:subject:references
>   :in-reply-to; bh=+vVumkeSjV1UdpDo3N/fd36LuEEOvN9i2NfWLJL56oI=;
>   b=BZLI4Xp0BVaDs0q46vQVBhybkV1YFZktAsRaUvBE/nA11yGB95ypLPFmXHI8oNPr/I
>   1mOfI8yGH0iwZQk76vH0vrcyuPHCdN0BFBVm74wZkE/SgqG5n7F/m0SWJH5JwdcSGhbh
>   vWX45oDIB47fVnRGfAqcYJ8W1B/mws+epy2wMnUmsA0ryVwAdZvXHDK9M8t50p0ug+yE
>   wFarOVydCBAgBC7igOaK7WLbXT5Zbh8S7DUdFSulcid+cGu07D/8zUByfOM2MivrRCCM
>   dI9MAVnhZ4qGEwr0DmV2rK8SuhEsPreoHSSd8W1G0WFxcGKW2DSTI5fCQrDEBfytR48K
>   Veyw==⁩ ⁨<5deecbf9.1c69fb81.4763e.1333.GMR@mx.google.com>⁩
>   ⁨<773b12e625f3a1a11b8f5a98d6dfa2bc@my_domain.com>⁩
>   X-Google-Dkim-Signature: ⁨v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
>   h=x-gm-message-state:to:auto-submitted:message-id:date:from:subject
>   :references:in-reply-to;
>   bh=+vVumkeSjV1UdpDo3N/fd36LuEEOvN9i2NfWLJL56oI=;
>   b=gOgOeh84ppQ43d9/8nNcBZL6XlyWUfyUmZqrlRJ1avyV6v5NBPn4mX/yCNRNY51l8y
>   s3U+Kwisej15JhEivmeVu8bRjnrPVFc/yS6wMsysjBu+/CSnuLsN89mpcW8hR1QfYSRF
>   YvmkfvyldbogDHcX4oJ0Pc7+CQEgdcSZ1WGOwzZrvsnc6pAijg6oVP8Bzh7pK5nsoJVq
>   rpOiZrbz4Ff7ziNJxzVXesbS4ld9Lcm32AEv8Er5eeUHLxEsfD04IfROpZeXgdjIQDPN
>   P/saIlV+p1r8wycZtURmNJnWbvGBWvBVDatFn+i6SkOXorDVfsqpx58rQabVfjyd1arH
>   KA5A==⁩ Content-Type: ⁨multipart/report;
>   boundary="000000000000eac82a05994cff10"; report-type=delivery-status⁩
>   Received-Spf: ⁨pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of
>   postmaster@mail-sor-f69.google.com designates 209.85.220.69 as
>   permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.220.69;⁩ Delivered-To:
>   ⁨my_address+caf_=my_address=me.com@gmail.com⁩ Received: ⁨by
>   2002:ac8:7593:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id s19csp4779624qtq; Mon, 9 Dec 2019
>   14:34:33 -0800 (PST)⁩ Received: ⁨from mail-sor-f69.google.com
>   (mail-sor-f69.google.com. [209.85.220.69]) by mx.google.com with SMTPS
>   id 61sor679175qva.7.2019.12.09.14.34.33 for
>    (Google Transport Security);
>   Mon, 09 Dec 2019 14:34:33 -0800 (PST)⁩ Received: ⁨by
>   2002:a05:6214:50f:: with SMTP id v15mr15815744qvw.42; Mon, 09 Dec 2019
>   14:34:33 -0800 (PST)

Comment: You probably have something set up that forwards or otherwise sends email to your @me.com address - i.e. this is not something that magically happens by itself. If you could include the complete email, including headers, in your question - then it would be possible to say more. Right now you haven't included enough information to pinpoint anything.

Comment: Gotcha.  I have no forwarder set up that I'm aware of.  The raw email is LONG so I didn't want to post the whole thing in case it wasn't really needed.  I'll add it in my question.

Comment: You seem to have left out the actual headers of the message, and only included the message body (which incidentially contains the headers of another mail). Can you include the full headers?

Comment: Weird that was "all headers" according to Mail.  Anyway issue is now resolved so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information given in your answer, it seems that you have setup some sort of forward or filtered forward in Gmail that targets your me.com address.

This can be seen in that you have "my_address+caf_=my_address=me.com@gmail.com⁩" listed. Gmail uses this way of mangling the actual return address to include "+caf_" and the target address with the @ substituted by a =, when it is forwarding mail like this.

Comment: Good lord... I just went digging through the settings in Gmail (which I haven't even logged into in I don't know how many years since I use the Mail.app) and sure enough, there was a forward set in there.  No idea when or why I would've set that up but, thanks for pointing me to it!